# Where is the default namespace name kept in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, namespaces

I created a new ASP.NET MVC application with a Project Name of "HelloWorld", and did some basic testing.  I then did a global rename of "HelloWorld" to "ApplicationName", but when I create a new controller, it still puts it into the "HelloWorld" namespace.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in Project Properties, as in any other C# project.